# Variable assignment problem with Insertion sort

Tags: java

In the following code implementing an insertion sort, it breaks completely when replacing `currentElement` with `nums[i]` (in the second for loop). As far as i can tell, `i` isn't changing until its next iteration. Even printing `i` and `currentElement` within the second for loop shows they are the same the whole time.

What goes wrong when using `nums[i]`?

```
public class InsertionSort {
  4         public static void main(String[] args){
  5                 int[] nums = {23,4,5234,1234,3,2,0,-44, -1239};
  6                 sort(nums);
  7                 
  8                 for (int i : nums) {
  9                         System.out.println(i);
 10                 }
 11                 
 12         }
 13
 14
 15         public static void sort(int[] nums) {
 16                 for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
 17                         int currentElement = nums[i];
 18                         int j;
 19                         for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && nums[j] > currentElement; j--) {
 20                                 nums[j + 1] = nums[j];
 21                         }
 22                         nums[j + 1] = currentElement;
 23                 }
 24         }
 25 }
```

If it matters the results are sorted naturally for `currentElement` and when using `nums[i]` this is how it was sorted:
4, 23, 1234, 3, 2, 0, -44, -1239, 5234.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing that your innermost loop does is change `nums[j+1]`; since `j=i-1`, this means it is changing `nums[i]`.